# Можно ли встроить одну диаграмму в другую в amCharts?

Tags: javascript

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей или знает, возможно ли ее реализовать?

Когда я нажимаю на элемент на графике, я хотел бы отобразить под ним 3 других графика, часть функционала получилась, но я не понимаю, как переместить другие элементы вниз...

Вот что должно произойти.

[Как это должно быть](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWL3L.png)

[codepen](https://codepen.io/3dmatern/pen/qBwBvpx)

```
const DATA = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Кузнецов Е.К.",
        production: 300,
        gzn: 60,
        loyalty: 70,
        firstChildren: [
            {
                name: "Январь 24",
                value: 222,
            },
            {
                name: "Февраль 17",
                value: 175,
            },
            {
                name: "Март 10",
                value: 47,
            },
            {
                name: "Прогноз",
                value: 192,
            },
            {
                name: "План",
                value: 201,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "Петров К.П.",
        production: 290,
        gzn: 60,
        loyalty: 70,
        firstChildren: [
            {
                name: "Январь 24",
                value: 222,
            },
            {
                name: "Февраль 17",
                value: 175,
            },
            {
                name: "Март 10",
                value: 47,
            },
            {
                name: "Прогноз",
                value: 192,
            },
            {
                name: "План",
                value: 201,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "Иванов П.И.",
        production: 280,
        gzn: 60,
        loyalty: 70,
        firstChildren: [
            {
                name: "Январь 24",
                value: 222,
            },
            {
                name: "Февраль 17",
                value: 175,
            },
            {
                name: "Март 10",
                value: 47,
            },
            {
                name: "Прогноз",
                value: 192,
            },
            {
                name: "План",
                value: 201,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        name: "Сидоров И.С.",
        production: 270,
        gzn: 60,
        loyalty: 70,
        firstChildren: [
            {
                name: "Январь 24",
                value: 222,
            },
            {
                name: "Февраль 17",
                value: 175,
            },
            {
                name: "Март 10",
                value: 47,
            },
            {
                name: "Прогноз",
                value: 192,
            },
            {
                name: "План",
                value: 201,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "5",
        name: "Алехно С.А.",
        production: 260,
        gzn: 60,
        loyalty: 70,
        firstChildren: [
            {
                name: "Январь 24",
                value: 222,
            },
            {
                name: "Февраль 17",
                value: 175,
            },
            {
                name: "Март 10",
                value: 47,
            },
            {
                name: "Прогноз",
                value: 192,
            },
            {
                name: "План",
                value: 201,
            },
        ],
    },
];

am5.ready(function () {
    // Create root element
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
    var root = am5.Root.new("stacked_click_bar_chart");

    // Set themes
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
    root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

    buildStackedClickBarChart(root, DATA);

    function buildStackedClickBarChart(root, data) {
        // Create chart
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
        let chart = root.container.children.push(
            am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
                paddingLeft: 0,
                paddingRight: 160,
                layout: root.verticalLayout,
            })
        );

        // Create axes
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
        let yRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
            inversed: true,
            cellStartLocation: 0.1,
            cellEndLocation: 0.9,
            minorGridEnabled: true,
        });

        yRenderer.grid.template.setAll({
            location: 1,
            forceHidden: true,
        });
        yRenderer.labels.template.set("forceHidden", true);

        let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
            am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
                categoryField: "name",
                renderer: yRenderer,
                tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {}),
            })
        );

        yAxis.data.setAll(data);

        let xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {});

        xRenderer.grid.template.set("forceHidden", true);
        xRenderer.labels.template.set("forceHidden", true);

        let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
            am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
                min: 0,
                maxPrecision: 0,
                calculateTotals: true,
                renderer: xRenderer,
            })
        );

        // Add legend
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/legend-xy-series/
        let legend = chart.children.push(
            am5.Legend.new(root, {
                paddingTop: 10,
                paddingBottom: 10,
                clickTarget: "none",
            })
        );

        legend.labels.template.setAll({
            width: 100,
        });
        legend.markers.template.setAll({
            width: 30,
            height: 15,
        });
        legend.markerRectangles.template.setAll({
            cornerRadiusTL: 10,
            cornerRadiusTR: 10,
            cornerRadiusBL: 10,
            cornerRadiusBR: 10,
        });

        // Add series
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
        function makeSeries(
            name,
            fieldName,
            { production, gzn, loyalty, sum }
        ) {
            var series = chart.series.push(
                am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
                    name: name,
                    xAxis: xAxis,
                    yAxis: yAxis,
                    valueXField: fieldName,
                    ...getSum(),
                    categoryYField: "name",
                    sequencedInterpolation: true,
                    stacked: true,
                    clustered: false,
                })
            );

            series.columns.template.events.on("click", function (ev) {
                // column id
                console.log("Clicked on a column", ev.target.uid);
                // data item
                console.log(ev.target.dataItem);
                // your original data object
                console.log(ev.target.dataItem.dataContext);
                // series
                console.log(ev.target.dataItem.component);
                var firstChildrenData =
                    ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.firstChildren;
                var chartFirstChildren =
                    ev.target.dataItem.component.children.push(
                        am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
                            width: am5.percent(33),
                            paddingLeft: 0,
                            paddingRight: 1,
                        })
                    );
                var xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
                    minGridDistance: 30,
                    minorGridEnabled: true,
                });

                xRenderer.labels.template.setAll({
                    rotation: 15,
                    centerY: am5.p50,
                    fontSize: 14,
                });
                xRenderer.grid.template.setAll({
                    location: 1,
                });

                var xAxisFirstChildren = chartFirstChildren.xAxes.push(
                    am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
                        maxDeviation: 0.3,
                        categoryField: "name",
                        renderer: xRenderer,
                        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {}),
                    })
                );
                var yRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
                    strokeOpacity: 0.1,
                });
                var yAxisFirstChildren = chartFirstChildren.yAxes.push(
                    am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
                        maxDeviation: 0.3,
                        renderer: yRenderer,
                    })
                );

                var seriesFirstChildren = chartFirstChildren.series.push(
                    am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
                        name: "Выработка + ГЗН + лояльность",
                        xAxis: xAxisFirstChildren,
                        yAxis: yAxisFirstChildren,
                        valueYField: "value",
                        sequencedInterpolation: true,
                        categoryXField: "name",
                        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
                            labelText: "{valueY}",
                        }),
                    })
                );

                seriesFirstChildren.columns.template.setAll({
                    cornerRadiusTL: 5,
                    cornerRadiusTR: 5,
                    strokeOpacity: 0,
                });
                seriesFirstChildren.columns.template.adapters.add(
                    "fill",
                    function (fill, target) {
                        return chart
                            .get("colors")
                            .getIndex(
                                seriesFirstChildren.columns.indexOf(target)
                            );
                    }
                );
                seriesFirstChildren.columns.template.adapters.add(
                    "stroke",
                    function (stroke, target) {
                        return chart
                            .get("colors")
                            .getIndex(
                                seriesFirstChildren.columns.indexOf(target)
                            );
                    }
                );

                xAxisFirstChildren.data.setAll(firstChildrenData);
                seriesFirstChildren.data.setAll(firstChildrenData);

                seriesFirstChildren.appear(1000);
                chartFirstChildren.appear(1000, 100);
            });

            series.columns.template.setAll({
                height: am5.p100,
                fill: getFillStroke(),
                cornerRadiusTR: 5,
                cornerRadiusBR: 5,
                strokeOpacity: 0,
                cursorOverStyle: "pointer",
            });
            series.data.setAll(data);

            // Make stuff animate on load
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
            series.appear();

            series.bullets.push(function () {
                return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
                    locationX: 1,
                    locationY: 0.5,
                    sprite: am5.Label.new(root, {}),
                });
            });

            series.bullets.push(function () {
                return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
                    locationX: 0,
                    locationY: 0.5,
                    sprite: production
                        ? am5.Label.new(root, {
                              centerY: am5.p50,
                              text: "[bold]{name}",
                              fill: am5.color(0xffffff),
                              populateText: true,
                          })
                        : null,
                });
            });

            if (loyalty) {
                series.bullets.push(function () {
                    var label = am5.Label.new(root, {
                        centerY: am5.p50,
                        fill: "#3EB489",
                        text: "{valueX}",
                        populateText: true,
                    });

                    label.adapters.add("text", function (text, target) {
                        var { production, gzn, loyalty } =
                            target.dataItem.dataContext;
                        var val = Math.abs(production + gzn + loyalty);
                        return `[bold]${val} тыс.`;
                    });

                    return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
                        locationX: 1,
                        locationY: 0.5,
                        sprite: label,
                    });
                });
            }

            legend.data.push(series);

            function getSum() {
                if (loyalty) {
                    return {
                        productionValueXField: sum.production,
                        gznValueXField: sum.gzn,
                    };
                }
            }

            function getFillStroke() {
                if (production) {
                    return "#3EB489";
                }
                if (gzn) {
                    return "#EEC759";
                }
                if (loyalty) {
                    return "#B08BBB";
                }
            }
        }

        makeSeries("Выработка", "production", { production: true });
        makeSeries("ГЗН", "gzn", { gzn: true });
        makeSeries("Лояльность", "loyalty", {
            loyalty: true,
            sum: {
                production: "production",
                gzn: "gzn",
            },
        });

        // Make stuff animate on load
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
        chart.appear(1000, 100);
    }
});
```